# Having issues with running npm start after installing chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, package.json, npm-start

I'm following along with a tutorial on building a bar chart in React from this YouTube video:[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_9c5zkfQ3Y]

After installing Chartjs and Chartjs-2 and then running npm start, I get the following error:

**Failed to compile**.

**Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from.
Referenced from: /mnt/c/Users/perez/dev/hometown-viewers/package.json**

This is from my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "hometown-viewers",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "chart.js": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I go about fixing this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The react wrapper is not compatible with version 3 of chart.js please downgrade to chart.js 2.9.4 (latest V2 release) by changing `"chart.js": "^3.0.2",` to `"chart.js": "^2.9.4",` in your dependencies block, run npm install again and it will work

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. I got the same error message. Do you know what else it can be?